# How do i get my game back

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

On Christmas I got a 3DS XL with new Super Mario Bros. 2 Gold Edition. I wanted to do a system transfer from my old 3DS. But after the transfer my Mario game was gone.

How should I get my game back?

Answer (score 2):

If you did a system transfer, it should have transferred the downloaded game and/or any save data as long as you followed all of the instructions, and moved the SD card from the old 3DS to the new one.

You can try redownloading the game from the 3DS eShop, if you connected your Nintendo ID to it and that information transferred appropriately, and you had it as a downloaded game instead of the physical card, but your save will likely be gone.

Comment: If this answer doesn't work in your case, you can always try contacting Nintendo support either over the phone or with their [online support chat](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/chat/en_na/chatStart.jsp?source=vru).

Answer (score 0):

When you get a new 3DS with a game pre-installed, and you transferred data to that 3DS, the game will be gone. Simply re-download it for free off the e-shop. Save data stays as I redownloaded games I already had digitally and all my progress stayed intact.